# Get id and text from all elements with class and put into JSON array

Tags: jquery, json, each

I'm doing a each function for all elements with a spesific class, but here it only fetches the last one, and not putting all of them into the JSON-array.

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MYGCM/1/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="324834" class="selected_pages">One</div>
<div id="436346" class="selected_pages">Two</div>
<div id="768653" class="selected_pages">Three</div>
```

Jquery

```
 var pages = new Object();
 var publish = [];

 $('.selected_pages').each(function () {
 pages.name = $(this).text();
 pages.id = this.id;
 publish.push({
     Pages: pages
 });
 });

 var json_pages = JSON.stringify(publish);

 alert(json_pages)
```

Any input on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each `selected_pages` you need to create a `page` object as shown below

```
var publish = [];

$('.selected_pages').each(function () {
    var pages = new Object();
    pages.name = $(this).text();
    pages.id = this.id;
    publish.push({
        Pages: pages
    });
});

var json_pages = JSON.stringify(publish);

alert(json_pages)
```

I would recommend using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) here

```
var pages = $('.selected_pages').map(function () {
    var page = new Object();
    page.name = $(this).text();
    page.id = this.id;
    return { Pages: page};
}).get();

var json_pages = JSON.stringify(publish);

console.log(json_pages)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DjW97/)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! Works great! :)

Comment: `var page = {}; ` instead of `new Object()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map()` function to build the array before your stringify it. Try this:

```
var pages = $('.selected_pages').map(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    return { Pages: { name: $el.text(), id = this.id } };
}).get();
var json_pages = JSON.stringify(pages);
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/MYGCM/3/

You actually want this:

```
var pages = new Object();
 var publish = [];

 $('.selected_pages').each(function () {
     var page = new Object();
     page.name = $(this).text();
     page.id = this.id;
     publish.push(page);
 });


pages["Pages"] = publish;

 var json_pages = JSON.stringify(pages);

 alert(json_pages)
```